# Bimodule Ext for Dynkin path algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra

Let $A=kQ$ be a path algebra of Dynkin type $Q$ and $B=A^{op} \otimes_k A$ the enveloping algebra of $A$. Note that $mod-B$ is just the category of $A$-bimodule and $A$ is a $B$-module.

For a B-module $M$ with $g_M:=grade(M):=\inf \{i \geq 0 | Ext_B^i(M,B) \neq 0\}$ define $W(M):=DExt_B^{g_M}(M,B)$ , where $D=Hom_K(-,K)$ is the duality. $W(M)$ is agian a $B$-module and we can apply $W(-)$ again to get $W^i(M)$ for $i \geq 0$ in this way.

> Question: Is it true that there is always exist $l,m$ with $m \geq 1$ such that $W^l(A) \cong W^{l+m}(A)$? Is it even true that $W^1(A) \cong W^{m}(A)$ for some $m \geq 2$?

Note that for $A$ linear oriented of type $A_n$, we have $W(A) \cong DHom_A(D(A),A)$ as $A$-bimodules and in all other types we have $W(A) \cong DExt_A^1(D(A),A)$ as $A$-bimodules.

For example for linear oriented $A_3$ we have $W^1(A) \cong W^5(A)$.

In this example, $W^1(A)$ and $W^2(A)$ have grade 2 and $W^3(A)$ and $W^4(A)$ have grade 0 ($W^4(A)$ is the unique indecomposable projective-injective $B$-module).

There is probably an easy reason in case this is true for all $Q$.

It is not true for non-Dynkin $Q$ for example for the Kronecker quiver it is false (I would think it is false for every non-Dynkin $Q$ and maybe there is a relation to the preprojective algebra).

This obvervation might be true for more general algebras. I have not yet found a counterexample for representation-finite algebras with finite global dimension.